# Help with definition of "flow"

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

My question concerns the distinction between an **orbit in a flow**, and a **continuous one-to-one image of $\mathbb R$**.  Here is a definition:

[image]

The next excerpt indicates that this shape:

[image]

is NOT an orbit of a flow.

[image]

---

**EDIT: I need someone to explain why $X$, the one-to-one image of $\mathbb R$ in picture, is not the orbit of a flow $\pi:X\times \mathbb R \to X$**

Comment: The intuition here should be, all the points are moving (or "flowing") around, and $\pi(x,t)$ tells you where the point $x$ will have flowed in $t$ seconds. If infinitesimals were a thing, you'd only need a function $f:X\to X$ telling you where $x$ will flow in an infinitesimal amount of time; since they're not a thing, the textbook uses a formulation with $\pi:X\times\Bbb R\to X$ instead. (My guess is that the idea with infinitesimals can be formalized using hyperreals and that it's equivalent to the $\pi$ formulation.)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems rather trivial that an orbit of a continuous group action is homogeneous.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen ah, possibly so.  If you care to elaborate I can shower you with points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to see that the depicted space is not the orbit of a flow is from the fact that it is not topologically homogeneous. (a fact 
that can be shown by a simple cut point argument)

For the same reason, it cannot be an orbit of any continuous action of a topological group on a topological space. To see this, consider first the
more general case of a group $G$ acting on a set $X$. It is not hard to
verify that $O \subset X$ is an orbit of this action if and only

- $O \ne \emptyset$,
- $\pi$ can be restricted to an action $\pi_O: O \times G \to O$, in other words $\pi[O \times G] = O$, and
- $\pi_O$ is a transitive action, i.e. for all $x, y \in O$ there is a $t \in G$ such that $\pi(x, t) = y$.

With the additional assumption that $X$ and $G$ have topologies for which
$\pi$ is continuous, it is clear that $\pi_O$ is also continuous and thus we have a continuous transitive group action on $O$. Since for every $t \in G$ the mappings $x \mapsto \pi_O(x, t)$ and $x \mapsto \pi_O(x, -t)$ are continuous and they are each other's inverse, they are homeomorphisms. 
Combined with the transitivity of $\pi_O$ this implies that $O$ is 
homogeneous.

Note that $G$ does not have to be any special kind of group and the 
topology chosen on $G$ is immaterial.
On the other hand the argument does not extend to actions of monoids, because they don't generally act by isomorphisms.

Comment: I'm being dense with this, but why is that mapping a homeomorphism?

Comment: I have inserted an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The map $\pi_x$ does not have to be one-to-one at all. Consider the map $\pi: X \times \mathbb R \rightarrow X$ given by $\pi(x,t)=x$. This is a perfectly valid flow yet the image of $\mathbb R$ under the motion through $x$ is the singleton $x$. This is about as "non injective" as maps come.

Comment: yes I understand that difference.  But what about the picture? Why is that not a flow?

Answer (score 1):

The picture is not the orbit of a flow because if $\pi_x$ is not one-to-one, then it is periodic. Suppose $\pi_x(t_0)=\pi_x(t_0+s)$ for some $s>0$. Then using property (ii) of flows, for any $t\in\Bbb R$ we have

$$\pi_x(t+s)=\pi(x,(t_0+s)+(t-t_0))=\pi(\pi(x,t_0+s),t-t_0)=\pi(\pi(x,t_0),t-t_0)=\pi(x,t)=\pi_x(t).$$

Comment: I still do not understand.  The picture is one-to-one...

Comment: The image is a one-to-one image of $\mathbb R$, in the same way the circle is a one-to-one image of $[0,\infty)$...

Comment: Yes it is. Biject it to $[0,2\pi)$ and apply the map $x\mapsto e^{ix}$. (Pinging @ForeverMozart as well)

Comment: @SheafKeef you may want to see the paper which classifies some one-to-one images of $\mathbb R$: http://sci-hub.cc/http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-cmv17i2n16/c/cm17216.pdf

Comment: @SheafKeef Of course it is. It "starts" at the tripoint (as in, the limit as you go to $-\infty$ is the tripoint), it goes counterclockwise once around the bulb, and then it heads right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's continuous at the tripoint. Consider the map $\pi(-,t)$ (that is, fix a $t$ and vary $x$).

Comment: what is your $\pi$?  It should be an arbitrary flow.  So your argument may not work, for instance, if $\pi$ is the first coordinate projection. On second thought, I kindof see what you're saying; I do believe a problem occurs at the tripoint.  But we have to use that additional flow property somehow.

Comment: If $\pi$ is the first coordinate projection, that corresponds to the trivial flow with all singleton orbits.

Comment: yes I know.  But your argument does not account for it.

Comment: @ForeverMozart It doesn't account for it because that's not your proposed flow. Your proposed flow, if I understand you correctly, has the points in the circle flow in a counterclockwise direction and the points on the line flow to the right.

Comment: If the flow has its orbits all singletons, it's not prohibited by classification in the textbook.